# How do I keep my Visual Studio breakpoints in sync with externally-changed code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control, breakpoints

I develop in Visual Studio on a codebase that's under source control. When I pull the latest changes from the repository, my breakpoints and bookmarks are now out of sync with the code. Is there any way of getting them to stay in sync?

(In case it matters, I'm using Perforce for source control - though considering switching to git for reasons unrelated to this question.)

Answer (score 2):

The breakpoint is set at a *specific* line number in the file (23, 147, 11679). If something else changes this line of code outside Visual Studio then it has no way of knowing that the code as potentially moved and even if it did where would it move the break point to?

I don't think changing source control provider will affect this.

There is the "Break at Function" command:

> Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function - Ctrl+D,N

[image: Break at Function dialog]

This allows you to set a break point relative to the start of a function rather than an position in a file.

Comment: Thanks - but somewhat strangely, if I set Line to be something other than 1 and hit OK, I get the message: "Function breakpoints are only supported on the first line."